# C - exec not outputting into pipe

Tags: c, exec, pipe, stdout, stdin

I am making a program that will eventually be able to work for (theoretically) any shell command passed to it. My problem is that the exec that runs will not put its output into the pipe, and instead when run it seems as if the initial call is going into the pipe instead? I tried flushing the stdout first but it will not work. Any help is appreciated!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i=0, pid;
    int dataPipe[2];
    pipe(dataPipe);

    char *newArgs[5] = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ls", "-a", NULL};

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {

        printf("Error: could not fork!");
        exit(2);
    }

    else if (pid == 0) {

        close(dataPipe[0]);
        fflush(stdout);

        dup2(dataPipe[1], 1);
        close(dataPipe[1]);

        if (execvp(newArgs[0], newArgs) < 0) {

            printf("Command Failed to exucute!");
            exit(3);
        }
    }

    else {

        char buf[BUFFER];
        close(dataPipe[1]);

        wait(0);
        printf("Command exexuted correctly!\n");

        while(read(dataPipe[0], buf, BUFFER) != 0) {
            printf("Here is the command's output:\n%s\n", buf);
        }

        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./doit ls -a                                       
Command exexuted correctly!
Here is the command's output:
d
@
Here is the command's output:
o
@
Here is the command's output:
i
@
Here is the command's output:
t
@
Here is the command's output:
@
Here is the command's output:
d
@
Here is the command's output:
o
@
Here is the command's output:
i
@
Here is the command's output:
t
@
Here is the command's output:
.
@
Here is the command's output:
c
@
Here is the command's output:


@
```

Comment: Please tell us what you observe first. Just the facts. "The program prints 'Sorry pal' and exits". It's a fact. "Output doesn't go to the pipe". That would be a theory.

Comment: I did say that newArgs was showing up but I will elaborate. The output is above.

Comment: You should probably use `{"/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -a", NULL}`.  However, the difference means you won't see the names that start with a dot.

Comment: Please check what you have defined as `BUFFER`. After inspecting your output I think it is very small, (possibly 1 ?)
Also not the program does list your files 'doit' and 'doit.c' (possibly these are the two in your working director).

Comment: works for me, with `#define BUFFER 256`.

Comment: 1. Increase BUFFER to a few hundred bytes. 2. `read` does not null-terminate the buffer, you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got everything correct. There are only couple of changes needed in your code to make everything work.

Change the lines:

```
    while(read(dataPipe[0], buf, BUFFER) != 0) {
        printf("Here is the command's output:\n%s\n", buf);
    }
```

to

```
    printf("Here is the command's output:\n");
    while( (count = read(dataPipe[0], buf, BUFFER)) != 0) {
       fwrite(buf, count, 1, stdout);
    }
```

The first change, moving the printing of `"Here is the command's output:\n"` should be obvious. You don't want to print that line every time some data is successfully read.

The second change is a little bit more subtle.

The line:

```
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

is quite different from the line:

```
fwrite(buf, count, 1, stdout);
```

There are couple of problems with the `printf` approach:

1. In the `printf` call, you are introducing newlines to the output for every successful completion of `read`, which are not there in the output of the forked process.
2. The `printf` command works only if `buf` is a null-terminated string. `read` does not create a null-terminated string. With `read`, you are getting an array of raw characters. By using `buf` in a place where a null-terminated string is expected, you are invoking undefined behavior.

Using `fwrite` instead of `printf` takes care of both issues. It does not print any additional newline characters. It only prints the exact numbers of bytes read from the pipe.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have realized that was the actual output not the command I typed in, lol.